# What are Wilson Coefficients?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, terminology, definition, effective-field-theory

I have seen this terminology in several papers but I haven't managed to find an explanation of what they actually are. I understand that they are related to effective field theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wilson coefficients are the coefficients/coupling constants in front of the various terms in the [Wilsonian effective action](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=wilsonian+effective+action). For formulas, see e.g. my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/700619/2451).